# Удаление лишних div'ов

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется div c id "chat-messages"

В него постепенно из бд добавляются div'ы с id "message-ID СООБЩЕНИЯ"

Пример:

```html
<div id="chat-messages">
<div id="message-1">Сообщение 1</div>
<div id="message-2">Сообщение 2</div>
<div id="message-3">Сообщение 3</div>
</div>
```

Надо удалять все старые дивы так, чтобы в блоке chat-messages было максимум 60 сообщений

JS:

```js
UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js = {
  messages_id: null,
  div_reload: true,
  tmp: {
    ci: '<div class="mainChat mainNew" id="mainChat"></div>',
    cm: [
      '<div id="subChat-closebar" onclick="UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.close()">Скрыть чат (Фонд: <span id="jchat-fond"></span>)</div><div id="subChat-messages"><span id="jchat-message"></span></div><input type="text" id="JChat-message" onkeyup="UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.keyboard(event.keyCode)" maxlength="300" style="width: 406px; left: -5px; position: relative;"><span class="f-buttons" style="left: -2px; position: relative;"> <span class="f-bu f-bu-success" onclick="UMBRELLA.modules.chat.postmsg()"><input type="button" class="chatSprite" id="chs-30"> Сказать</span> <span class="f-bu"><input id="chs-31" class="chatSprite" type="button"> Бар</span></span>',
      '<div id="subChat-closebar" onclick="UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.open()">Показать чат</div>'
    ]
  },
  fa: {
    fp: function() {
      $('body').append(UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.tmp.ci);
      $('#mainChat').append(UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.tmp.cm[0]);
      return true;
    }
  },
  keyboard: function(kid) {
    if (kid == 13) UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.action.post();
  },
  close: function() {
    UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.div_reload = false;
    $(".mainChat").html(UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.tmp.cm[1]);
  },
  open: function() {
    UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.div_reload = true;
    UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.messages_id = 0;
    $(".mainChat").html(UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.tmp.cm[0]);
    UMBRELLA.modules.javax.call($.toJSON({
      request: "chat",
      type: "getChats",
      id: UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.messages_id
    }));
  },
  calls: {
    make: function(a) {
      if (UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.fa.fp()) {
        a();
        $.cookie('tmp_jchat_rt', 0);
      }
    },
    jchat: function(a) {
      var c = JSON.parse(a);
      if (c.request == 'chat') {
        if (c.type == 'jchaterror') {
          if (c.errid == '001') {
            UMBRELLA.plugins.mainWindow.message('Ошибка!', 'Заполните поле сообщения перед отправкой.');
          } else if (c.errid == '002') {
            UMBRELLA.plugins.mainWindow.message('Ошибка!', 'Вы отключены от чата на ' + c.time + ' минут. Причина: ' + c.reason + '.');
          }
        }
        if (c.type == 'chats') {
          $("#jchat-fond").text(c.fond);
          if (!c.messages) {
            return false;
          }
          for (var i = 0; i < c.messages.length; i++) {
            UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.messages_id = c.messages[i].id;
            $("#jchat-message").prepend('<div class="subChat-message" id="jchat-' + c.messages[i].id + '" ' + (c.messages[i].touser[0] == MY.id ? 'style="background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.1);border: solid 1px #093406;"' : '') + '><span>' /* */ + (c.messages[i].system == 3 ? '<font color="#32CD32"><b>' + c.messages[i].message + '</b></font>' : (c.messages[i].system == 2 ? '<span><b><div class="f-bwi"><img class="f-bwi-pic" width="84" height="85" alt="Gold" src="/img/1353213729.png"></img><div class="f-bwi-text"><input id="spriteRank' + c.messages[i].user[0] + '" class="sprite" type="button"></input> <b>' + c.messages[i].message + '</b><br>Поймал бонусный ящик с 100 еденицами опыта.</div></div></b></span>' : (c.messages[i].system == 0 ? /* */ (c.messages[i].pm != 0 ? '[PM]' : '') + '<input style="box-shadow: none; background-color: transparent;" type="button" class="sprite" id="spriteRank' + c.messages[i].user[0] + '" /><b>' + c.messages[i].user[1] + '</b></span>' + (c.messages[i].touser.length != 0 ? ' → <span><input style="box-shadow: none; background-color: transparent;" type="button" class="sprite" id="spriteRank' + c.messages[i].touser[0] + '" /><b>' + c.messages[i].touser[1] + '</b>:</span> ' : ': ') + c.messages[i].message /**/ : 'Наблюдатель'))) /**/ + '</div>');
          }
        }
      }
    },
    open: function(a) {
      if (a[0] == 'chat') {
        var b = (function() {
          UMBRELLA.modules.javax.call($.toJSON({
            request: "chat",
            type: "getChats",
            id: "0"
          }))
        });
      }
      UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.calls.make(b);
    },
    refresh: function(a) {
      if (UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.div_reload != false) {
        if (a != 'post') {
          if ($.cookie('tmp_jchat_rt') < Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)) {
            UMBRELLA.modules.javax.call($.toJSON({
              request: "chat",
              type: "getChats",
              id: UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.messages_id
            }));
          }
        } else {
          UMBRELLA.modules.javax.call($.toJSON({
            request: "chat",
            type: "getChats",
            id: UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.messages_id
          }));
        }
      }
    }
  },
  action: {
    post: function() {
      var message = $("#JChat-message").val();
      $("#JChat-message").attr("value", "");
      var b = UMBRELLA.modules.javax.call($.toJSON({
        request: "chat",
        type: "setMessages",
        text: message
      }));
      UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.calls.refresh('post');
      $.cookie('tmp_jchat_rt', Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) + 1500);
    }
  }
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    UMBRELLA.modules.jchat.js.calls.refresh()
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: как добавляются?

Comment: @Grundy Запрос к php файлу, а тот из бд

Comment: добавьте ваш яваскрипт код

Comment: @Grundy Добавил

Comment: Можно что-то типа такого: https://jsfiddle.net/maoq30vh/; запускать после добавления (писал на скорую засыпаючи, не судите строго).

Comment: @w3lifer Огромное спасибо, то, что надо!